# Marshal into a bson.Raw

Tags: go, marshalling, bson, mgo

Using [`gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson`](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson), I wonder how to marshal an interface{} value into a value of type `bson.Raw`.

[The documentation](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Raw) for `bson.Raw` states:

> Using this type it is possible to unmarshal or *marshal* values partially.

But I can't find a Marshal function that would return `bson.Raw`.

What am I missing?

**Example of what I try to do:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

func main() {
    // How to avoid a MarshalRaw help function?
    raw, err := MarshalRaw("Hello world")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", raw)
}

func MarshalRaw(v interface{}) (*bson.Raw, error) {
    bin, err := bson.Marshal(struct{ Raw interface{} }{v})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var raw struct{ Raw bson.Raw }
    err = bson.Unmarshal(bin, &raw)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &raw.Raw, nil
}
```

**Output:**

> &{Kind:2 Data:[12 0 0 0 72 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100 0]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bson.Raw](https://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Raw) is used as a value both when marshaling and unmarshaling.

To transform an `interface{}` into a `bson.Raw`, the first thing to do is to marshal it so that you get the plain document data that represents whatever is being marshaled:

```
    var value interface{} = bson.M{"some": "value"}
    data, err := bson.Marshal(value)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

and then it may have one or more fields unmarshaled into `bson.Raw` values:

```
    var doc struct{ Some bson.Raw }
    err = bson.Unmarshal(data, &doc)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

or even the entire document:

```
    var doc bson.Raw
    err = bson.Unmarshal(data, &doc)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

If you want the entire document rather than just a field, you can also use this shortcut:

```
    doc := bson.Raw{3, data}
```

The 3 constant represents a document in the [bson specification](http://bsonspec.org), and it must of course match the provided data. Since BSON only supports documents at the top level, we know this must be correct.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that bson.Raw is intended to be used as a type for a variable.

for example: (in [play](http://play.golang.org/p/V5Lf60NT3Y))

```
type Bar struct {
   AnInt int
   AString bson.Raw
}
```

The "AString" field will be kept as the bson.Raw struct your link mentions.

This is super-useful if you want to partially decode the top level of a nested structure to figure out its actualy type so you can parse the rest in to the proper datatype.

Note, the above is untested, not in front of a machine I can actually run go on at the moment.  This is based on the assumption that it works like the standard encoding/json package.

Comment: Yes, it is also my intention and covers the partial *unmarshalling* of the struct. But when you want to Insert a `Bar` value into the database, you want to set the `AString` value. How to create this `bson.Raw` value from a normal string (or any other type)? After all, the documentation mentions "marshal values partially", and the Playground solution of using a separate struct, `Foo`, to do the marshalling is not "partial".

Comment: I've added an example of a workaround. It is not pretty though.

Answer (score 1):

Solution I was looking for

```
m := bson.M{"ns": bson.M{"coll": "test1", "db": "testdb"}}
data, _ := bson.Marshal(m)
r := bson.Raw(data)
coll := r.Lookup("ns", "coll").StringValue()
println(coll)
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/1S_dYgKmprj)