# MongoDB Return entire JSON from query using bson.Raw

Tags: json, mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to search for this document:

```
"meta": {
    "pageId": "...",
    "userId": "...",
    "ver": "0",
},
"dialog": {
 ...

 }
```

and get the entire `"dialog"` as a JSON, so I created this struct:

```
type Dialog struct {
    Dialog bson.Raw `json:"dialog" bson:"dialog"`
}
```

So I query the document like this:

```
dialog := Dialog{}
query := c.Find(locate).One(&dialog)
```

and when I print `dialog`, I get a bunch of numbers, which I believe are the raw bytes from the query.

The question is: how to unmarshal it into a JSON object?

The only thing I've found about this are [Marshal into a bson.Raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276884/marshal-into-a-bson-raw) (which doesn't explain how to unmarshal into a json)

**Update**

Following [How to marshal json string to bson document in golang for writing to MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785289/how-to-marshal-json-string-to-bson-document-in-golang-for-writing-to-mongodb), I did:

```
fmt.Println(bson.UnmarshalJSON(dialog.Dialog.Data, &a))
```

which gets me:

```
json: unknown constant "l"
```

As you can see I had to extract the `Data` from the [Raw type](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Raw), I don't think this is the best way to do it since there's the `Kind` field which is not being used. Also, what's this 'l'?

**Update 2**

I thought I had to Unmarshal into a JSON type in order to work with it but I've found that's better to Unmarshal to a map directly, so here it is:

```
var a bson.M
fmt.Println(bson.Unmarshal(dialog.Dialog.Data, &a))
fmt.Println(a)
```

It worked for me :)

However, I'm still ignoring the `Kind` field of the `Raw` type. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is not a type, so you can't unmarshal into a value of type JSON. [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a textual representation of some structured data.

[`bson.Raw`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Raw) is also not equal to JSON representation, so some kind of transformation is inevitable.

What you may do is unmarshal into a value of type `interface{}`, and then use [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) to "render" the JSON representation.

If you want this to be "automatic", you may create a new type called `JSONStr`, and you may implement the [`bson.Setter`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Setter) and [`bson.Getter`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Getter) interfaces by it.

This is how it could look like:

```
type JSONStr string

func (j *JSONStr) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) (err error) {
    var i interface{}
    if err = raw.Unmarshal(&i); err != nil {
        return
    }
    data, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    *j = JSONStr(data)
    return
}

func (j *JSONStr) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    var i interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(*j), &i); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return i, nil
}
```

And using this `JSONStr` type:

```
type Dialog struct {
    Dialog JSONStr `bson:"dialog"`
}
```

**Update:**

If you don't really want a JSON text representation, just use type `interface{}`:

```
type Dialog struct {
    Dialog interface{} `bson:"dialog"`
}
```

And obtain the JSON text like this:

```
var dialog Dialog
// load a dialog
data, err := json.Marshal(dialog.Dialog)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
fmt.Println(string(data))
```

(Basically this is what the `JSONStr.SetBSON()` method did exactly.)

Note that `interface{}` will "cover" all data structures. If you know it's an object, you may use a map. If you know it's an array, you may use a slice, etc. You may also use any concrete type.

Comment: I actually perceived that I didn't want to have a json, I just wanted to be able to deal with the data in some way. Now I've found the Unmarshal function and Unmarshaled it into a map. However, while doing it, I'm ignoring the Raw.kind field, I'm extracting the Raw.Data directly. Could you look at my update2? Is this the best way to deal with generic data returned from a MongoDB query?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs No, it's not. The `Kind` field is to tell how to interpret the `Data` field. Ignoring it will cause you troubles. Also, let the `mgo` package handle that for you. Also unmarshaling into a map will also give you errors if the value is an array. To cover all cases, unmarshal into a value of type `interface{}`, like I did in my answer.

Comment: You're right, I did it and it worked. However, in order to access its members, I have to admit it's a map and cast to it. Is it bad to do like this? Because how did I know that it'd unmarshal into a map?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs If you know it's a map, yes, you can use a map. Going even further, if you know all its fields prior, just create a `struct` modeling it exactly, and unmarshal into a value of that type. You can also use `json.Marshal()` on your custom types.